# Angular module-federation with Kubernetes

Tags: angular, kubernetes, dockerfile, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am new to micro-frontends. I have created two simple applications, where the first displays 2 menu points of which the first is handled by the host app itself, while when clicking on the second it is handled by the remote-app and it is returning some basic hardcoded data, which I then display in the main app. I am using module-federation with Angular for this setup. It is working as it should, the data is coming from the remote-app and is displayed correctly. But when I want to extend this, so introducing Docker and Kubernetes I am having difficulty with achieving the same result. My files currently look like this:

webpack.config.js for host-app:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "hostApp",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "hostApp",
        remotes: {
          // "remoteApp1": "mfeApp@http://localhost:4300/remoteEntry.js",
          "remoteApp1": "mfeApp@http://my-app.com/remoteEntry.js",
        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

webpack.config.js for remote-app:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "remoteApp1",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "remoteApp1",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './TodoListModule': './src/app/todo-list/todo-list.module.ts',
        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Dockerfile for the first project:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
```

Dockerfile for the second project:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4300

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4300"]
```

The yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: exp-host-mf-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: exp-host-mf-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: exp-host-mf-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: exp-host-mf-app
          image: testexampleuser/exp-host-mf-app:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4200

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: exp-host-mf-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: exp-host-mf-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6001
      targetPort: 4200

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: exp-remote-1-mf-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: exp-remote-1-mf-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: exp-remote-1-mf-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: exp-remote-1-mf-app
          image: testexampleuser/exp-remote-1-mf-app:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4300

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: exp-remote-1-mf-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: exp-remote-1-mf-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6002
      targetPort: 4300

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /exp-host
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: exp-host-mf-app
                port:
                  number: 6001
          - path: /exp-remote
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: exp-remote-1-mf-app
                port:
                  number: 6002
```

I am using Minikube, and have ingress addon enabled. I created an entry in the host file:

`127.0.0.1 my-app.com`

After executing minikube tunnel, when I navigate to http://my-app.com/exp-host I see Invalid Host header. What am I doing wrong?